# How to set the PYTHONPATH to the current directory on windows

Tags: makefile, windows-10, ubuntu-20.04, pythonpath

I have this project that has a makefile, which sets the pythonpath to the current directory using `PYTHONPATH=$(shell pwd)`. But I know that the way used is applied only in linux. The way to dodge that is by using a linux os or wsl ubuntu terminal, but I want to dodge all of that. So the full part in the makefile is:

```
CONFIG_PATH=./experiments/configs/
CONFIG_NAME=seld.yml
OUTPUT=./outputs   # Directory to save output
EXP_SUFFIX=_test   # the experiment name = CONFIG_NAME + EXP_SUFFIX
RESUME=False
GPU_NUM=0  # Set to -1 if there is no GPU

.phony: train
train:
    PYTHONPATH=$(shell pwd) CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="${GPU_NUM}" python experiments/train.py --exp_config="${CONFIG_PATH}${CONFIG_NAME}" --exp_group_dir=$(OUTPUT) --exp_suffix=$(EXP_SUFFIX) --resume=$(RESUME)
```

If I want to have the same effect but on windows, how should it be edited?
I have searched for this, but there is nothing much useful that I found. All the answers found was for linux. I know that I can set the pythonpath on windows in the system environment variables, but I don't know how should the line change in that case? And whether or not adding the pythonpath to my system environmnetal variables is the thing to do or not?

Answer (score 3):

GNU Make has the built-in variable CURDIR which has the absolute path to current working directory: `PYTHONPATH=$(CURDIR)`.

But you could instead provide it as a relative path, in which it becomes just `PYTHONPATH=.`.

---

I realize that won't work in a Windows shell. You'd instead set it using a target specific variable:

```
train: export PYTHONPATH=.
```